# why we use kmeans.fit function in kmeans clustering method?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am using kmeans clustering technique from a video but i do not understand why we use .fit method in kmeans clustering?

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=0)
kmeans.fit(X) //why we use this fit method here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**kmeans** is your defined model.

To **train** our model , we use **kmeans.fit()** here.

The argument in

> **kmeans.fit(argument)**

is our data set that need to be Clustered.

After using the

> **fit()** function

our model is ready.

And we get **labels** for that clusters using

> data_labels = kmeans.labels_

Answer (score 0):

Because the sklearn people early on decided that *everything* should have `fit(X, y)` and `predict(X)` functions. And it likely is not going to change, because of backwards compatibility...

It does not make a whole lot of sense for clustering, which does not use `y` (which defaults to `None` as it is ignored). And there is no real use case where you would want to drop-in replace a classifier with a clustering, either.

Nevertheless, you'll at some point need to *run* the algorithm. It is an anti-pattern to do this in a constructor (so `KMeans(n_clusters=5, data=X)` is a no-no), so you will have to invoke some method. You may as well call it `fit` then, which fits at least for optimization based methods such as k-means.

You could, however, simply use the method `k_means(X, n_clusters=5)` instead of using the class. Then it would be a single line (see the source code of `fit` for an example).